# Getting rid of the horizontal line between abstract and the text of an article

Tags: article, abstract

I am using an article using informs3.cls. I want to get rid of the line between abstract and the text, because abstract is taking the entire first page, and the line sits at the top of the second page.

Please help me on this.

Best,
Ovunc

Comment: Welcome to new site of TeX.SE. Excuse me for this comment: I understood very little because in the meantime his code is missing what we call minimal working example, an acronym MWE, and we don't even have the working class `informs3.cls`. Could you add them please? We are all ready to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The rule can be removed with the following redefinition:

```
\documentclass{informs3}

\ABSTRACT{test}

\def\theARTICLERULE{%
  \begin{Center}
  \vspace*{12pt}
%  \VRHDW{1pt}{0pt}{\textwidth}
  \vspace*{4pt}
  \HOOKc
  \end{Center}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


test
\end{document}
```